# Sending an email with attachment in Xamarin.Forms for Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am creating an app to send an email with an attachment. I have tried using `mailTo` to do it but it is not working. Are there any other ways to send an email with attachment?

This is the code that I have tried so far

```
private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string toEmail = "toemail@nyp.edu.sg";
    string emailSubject = "Test Email";
    string emailBody = "Email Body";
    string attachment = "C:/Users/L30901/Desktop/download.jpg";

    Device.OpenUri(new Uri(String.Format("mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}&attachment=file:///{3}", toEmail, emailSubject, emailBody, attachment)));
}
```

This is what I did for iOS

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IDependency>().SendEmail();
}
```

**IDependency.cs**

```
public interface IDependency
{
    void SendEmail();
}
```

**IOSEmail.cs**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IOSEmail))]
namespace Notification.iOS
{
    public class IOSEmail : IDependency
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController mailController;

        public void SendEmail()
        {
            if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
            {
                mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();

                mailController.SetToRecipients(new string[] { "some.person@somewhere.com" });
                mailController.SetSubject("Testing");
                mailController.SetMessageBody("See attached file", false);

                NSData data = NSData.FromFile(pdffilename);
                mailController.AddAttachmentData(data, "application/jpeg", "xxxxx.jpg");// For JPEG

                mailController.Finished += HandleMailFinished;

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
            }
        }

        private void HandleMailFinished(object sender, MFComposeResultEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
        }
```

Comment: *but not working* : what is the error? Add that to your question please

Comment: There is no error coming out. Visual Studio runs as per normal but once i click the button in the email app everything will be populated except the attachment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: And please: only use the relevant tag. Android, ios, which is it?

Comment: @GhostCat if hes using Xamarin.Forms it would be both of them.

Comment: @Woj The question is rather: on which device does he test? Because that guides how he might get to more tracing/logging information, which is essential here.

Comment: I tried this in the default android emulator in Visual Studio. And this app is a cross platform app so i will be using this in iOS also.

Comment: The attachment URL  is wrong . the file have to be on  the emulator ( with the right permissions on android )

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed So what is the alternative way i need to do

Comment: I have updated your question as per my understanding of it please have a look and if that is what you meant to do!

Comment: @G.hakim Thanks and yes this what i meant to do.

Comment: @IrfaanAhmed I have added an answer for android take a look until then i upload the iOS bit of it

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do can only be done using `Xamarin.Forms` [**DependencyService**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction):

**For Android you need to do something like this:**

1. Get the Directory of your attachment using Java.IO:

   ```
   Java.IO.File dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
   ```

   **Note**: I have used the downloads directory you can change it as per your need at any point in time.
2. Once you are done with picking that directory using Android OS environment then pick the file something like this;

   ```
   Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(dir, "yourFile.pdf"); //This could be any other type of file aswell
   ```
3. Get the URI of that Android file something like this:

   ```
    Android.Net.Uri path = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
   ```
4. Create the Intent to send the data from to your Emailing app something like this:

   ```
       var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
       email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
       new string[] { "some.person@somewhere.com" }); // to whom you want to send the email
       email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
       new string[] { "some.person@somewhereelse.com" }); // to whom you want to Copy in the email (CC)
       email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Awesome File");
       email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
       "See attached file");
       email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, path);
       email.SetType("message/rfc822");
       StartActivity(email);
   ```

**For IOS you need to do something like this:**

5. Create an instance of `MFMailComposeViewController` and add a subject and message body to it;

   ```
   var mailer= new MFMailComposeViewController();
   mailer.SetSubject("xxxx");
   mailer.SetMessageBody("", true);
   mailer.Finished += HandleMailFinished; //This controllers finished event in case you need it
   ```
6. Now it is mandatory that you have your file in the document directory for it to be available to the application for more information check [Working with the File System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system)
7. Assuming that you read that and you have added the file to the document directory of your application get the NSData for your attachment:

   ```
    NSData data = NSData.FromFile(pdfFileName);
    mailer.AddAttachmentData(data, "application/pdf", "xxxxx.pdf");// For PDF
    mail.AddAttachmentData(csvdata, "application/csv", "csv.txt"); // For CSV/TXT
   ```
8. Get the currently displayed Viewcontroller something like this:

   ```
      public UIViewController GetCurrentUIController()
   {
       UIViewController viewController;
       var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
       if (window == null)
       {
           return null;
       }

       if (window.RootViewController.PresentedViewController == null)
       {
           window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows
                    .First(i => i.RootViewController != null &&
                                i.RootViewController.GetType().FullName
                                .Contains(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform).FullName));
       }

       viewController = window.RootViewController;

       while (viewController.PresentedViewController != null)
       {
           viewController = viewController.PresentedViewController;
       }

       return viewController;
   }
   ```
9. Then Present the Viewcontroller something like this:

   ```
   var _CurrentViewComtroller= GetCurrentUIController();
   _CurrentViewComtroller?.PresentViewController(mailer, true, null);
   ```
10. The Handled Finish method would be something like this:

    ```
     private void HandleMailFinished(object sender, MFComposeResultEventArgs args)
     {
         DismissViewController (true, null);
     }
    ```

Comment: Thanks for sharing I will try this method and get back to you

Comment: i have updated iOS as well take a look and let me know if it worked for you

Comment: I am not able to do the first step vs is showing a few errors like "The type or namespace name could not be found" and "Android does not contain a definition for OS" can you help me with this

Comment: It is working for me so I don't understand what exactly are you doing here!

Comment: This code should be put in the shared folder or under the android folder

Comment: Under the android folder of course, that is whole reason i told you to look into dependency services

Comment: Sorry about that I still new to this I am figuring out and thanks for quick response

Comment: No problem let me know in case you are still facing the issue

Comment: Sure I will try and get back to you

Comment: Do I need to put the codes in the main method or create another method. And after that how do I call the method from the page that I created

Comment: Check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nirmal.hota/working-with-dependencyservice-in-xamarin/) it has an example of how to use dependency services properly

Comment: I am getting error at the StartActivity(email) stating "The name StartActivity does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Use the [currentActivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) plugin to get the context for android

Comment: Do I need to use the Dependency Service for iOS to and also do I need to create a class or viewcontroller for iOS to put inside this codes.

Comment: Yes you need a dependency service for ios as well and you need to use a class and not a view controller

Comment: Ok I used dependency service and class but when I press the button I am not getting anything. Will using the same dependency service interface cause the problem

Comment: This is what I have in my xaml under the button click method DependencyService.Get<IDependency>().SendEmail();

Comment: Can you update your code into the question so it would be easier to understand, Update all the changes that you have done so far for iOS

Comment: I have updated my code in the question ready please take a look

Comment: so what exactly is the problem here i mean everything looks okay to me ?

Comment: I am not sure also when I click the button there is nothing coming out

Comment: Did you try debugging in your send mail method and check if it gets called?

Comment: Not yet but will be debugging

Comment: Do it and check if it gets called properly or not

Comment: Ok I will check and get back to you